# Toggle Editing Add Feature

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqt, pyqgis-3

i have loaded the layers in qgis from database.
so after picking "toggle editing" plugin,the other corresponding plugin are in disabled state only,they are not enabled.how to set "add feature" plugin enabled using pyqgis.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code

```
# Find the layer to edit
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
# Implement the Add Feature button
qgis.utils.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
```

Then add the features you wish to add to the layer.